# ggplot not adding legend. What am I missing? very new to R

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, scale, legend

I'm plotting three samples with ggplot but it's not adding a legend for the samples. It's not spitting out any error message so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'd really appreicate some guidance.

I've tried to declare color for each sample for the legend manually but there is still no legend on the plot.

```
df<-data.frame(samples$V1, samples$V2, samples$V3, samples$V4, samples$V5, samples$V6, samples$V7)


CG_methplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=samples$V1,))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=number_ticks(10))+
  xlab("bins")+
  ylab("mean CG methylation")+
  geom_point(aes(y=samples$V2), size=3, colour='#009933')+
  geom_point(aes(y=samples$V3), size=3, colour='#FF0000')+
  geom_point(aes(y=samples$V4), size=3, colour='#0033FF')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("samples1"="009933", "sample2"="FF0000", "sample3" ="0033FF"))
CG_methplot
```

As requested, sample data.

> head(df)

```
samples.V1 samples.V2 samples.V3 samples.V4 samples.V5 samples.V6 samples.V7
1          1   0.033636   0.027857   0.028830   0.029836   0.024457   0.024930
2          2   0.032094   0.029620   0.028005   0.028294   0.026220   0.024105
3          3   0.032011   0.027212   0.029728   0.028211   0.023812   0.025828
4          4   0.030857   0.029833   0.028907   0.027057   0.026433   0.025007
5          5   0.028480   0.028080   0.028553   0.024680   0.024680   0.024653
6          6   0.029445   0.027099   0.029346   0.025645   0.023699   0.025446
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data by adding the output of `dput(head(df))` to the question? The short answer is that you want to  use `melt` from `reshape2` then plot with just one call to `geom_point`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
melted <- melt(df, id.vars = "V1")

p <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = V1, y = value, colour = variable))
p + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a side note, what if I wanted to just plot the first three or last three samples? What sort of syntax would I use? Something like this?? p <- ggplot(melted, aes(x=samples.V1, y=variable[1-3]))

Comment: @user1995839 Subset the data that you give to `ggplot` ie `ggplot(melted[1:3,], aes(x = V1, y = value, colour = variable))`