# Plotting a line graph with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

So I have a large data set which is entitled `Site.377` On the x-axis I want the time which is in the `X` column and then the other 4 columns are entitled `Results1`, `Results2`, and `Results3`. I want to put them all on the same graph to compare how Results1 through 3 compare with each other over time.

What I currently did is:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Site.377, aes(x=X, y = Results1) #This was just an attempt to get one of them to post
p + geom_line()
```

When I would do this, the resulting plot would just have all of the numerical values smushed together and stacked to the side. Seems like a column of numbers overlapped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 X  Results1 Results2
 1     0       .23
 2    .83       0
 3    .56      .62
 4     0       .11
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data by posting the output of `dput(head(Site.377))`. `reshape2::melt` before plotting and adding `colour` to `aes` is probably what you want to do similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616688/ggplot-not-adding-legend-what-am-i-missing-very-new-to-r/21616934#21616934

Comment: The amount of data in the set is far too large to post the results in dput(head(Site.377)). I just tried: ggplot(Site.377, aes(x=X, y=Results1)) + geom_line(colour="black")

and had the same results. I may have misinterpreted what you said though.

Comment: Can you provide just first few columns of the data then? Like `dput(head(Site.377[1:10]))`. Or create data that has the same characteristics and creates the same issue. I'm guessing something like this will work `dfm <- melt(Site.377, id.vars = "X"); ggplot(dfm, aes(x = X, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()`

Comment: I made an edit with a little bit of a sample. It also should be noted that there are columns in this data set that I don't want to grab like a column called "Full.Profile" which is not needed and may be irrelevant to any discussion here.

Answer (score 4):

Any columns you don't want you can just leave out by subsetting `Site.377` before you melt it. Or subset based on `variable` after you melt it

Lucky guess in the comments :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


dfm <- melt(Site.377, id.vars = "X")

p <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x = X, y = value, colour = variable))
p + geom_line()
```

[image]